# QPushButton tab highlight signal

Tags: python, pyqt, focus, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I'm using PyQt to design an app. For accessibility reasons, I want to speak the name of a button when it is highlighted (using navigation by tab key.)

I have the speech down okay using Windows Speech API. Now I want to use signals and slots, but QPushButton doesn't seem to have a signal for when it is highlighted. The ones I have found are clicked, destroyed, pressed, released, toggled. None of them work.

Is there any way to set up a custom signal that will be emitted when the button is highlighted by tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QApplication` is responsible for managing widget focus, so you could connect to its [focusChanged](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#focusChanged) signal:

```
    QtGui.qApp.focusChanged.connect(self.handleFocusChanged)
```

The signal sends references to the previous/current widget that has lost/received the focus (by whatever means), so the handler might look like this:

```
    def handleFocusChanged(self, old, new):
        if old is not None and new is not None:
            if isinstance(new, QtGui.QPushButton):
                print('Button:', new.text())
            elif isinstance(new, QtGui.QLineEdit):
                print('Line Edit:', new.objectName())
            # and so forth...
```

You can also get the widget that currently has the focus using:

```
    widget = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
```

Comment: Works like a charm for now, but will it work if the focus shifts to a child of a child of the main window? For instance, I have a QHBox as central widget, which has two QVBox layouts as children, each of which has a bunch of buttons/lineEdits in them. So if the focus shifts to one of the lowest level widgets, will the signal pass it, or an ancestor?

Comment: The application manages *all* the widgets in the focus-chain of the currently active window. A `focusChanged` signal will also be emitted when the active window changes, but either of `old` or `new` will be set to `None`, depending on which window is losing or receiving the focus.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer by @ekhumoro works, and is the better way (in my opinion), it is also possible to achieve this by subclassing the QPushButton. Something like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class FocusButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FocusButton, self).__init__(parent)

    tabSignal = pyqtSignal()
    def focusInEvent(self, QFocusEvent):
        self.emit(SIGNAL('tabSignal()'))
```

It is now possible to create FocusButton objects instead of QPushButton, and they will emit the tabSignal whenever they receive focus.